# Can't seem to reset component state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm trying to reset the date value/text inside react-datepicker when user enters an invalid date. Here is the code:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: Date.now()
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DatePicker
        name="date"
        selected={this.state.date && moment(this.state.date, "x")}
        onChange={date => {
          this.setState({
            date: date.valueOf()
          });
        }}
        onBlur={e => {
          let date = moment(e.target.value, "LLL", true);
          if (date.isValid()) {
            this.setState({
              date: date.valueOf() // apply good value
            });
          } else {
            this.forceUpdate();
          }
        }}
        showTimeSelect
        timeFormat="HH:mm"
        timeIntervals={30}
        dateFormat="LLL"
        timeCaption="Time"
        minDate={moment().add(30, "minutes")}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to put it into JSFiddle but it seems to be having trouble with rendering react-datepicker component, yet this component renders fine in my own code.

The problem seems to be that `forceUpdate` isn't triggering a reset of the component. I'm wondering if the reset only occurs to the calendar selection itself and not the input field (which is what I'm trying to do). I tried adding `value` property and setting it to the same thing as `selected` property but it has no effect. The validation is firing and working as expected, but the rerendering on the input field text is not.

Comment: how about to apply Date.now() to `date` state instead of `forceUpdate`?

Comment: Same issue, it updates when changing via calendar, but not when changing the text directly, even though the blur event fires at the right time in both cases. There is also `onChangeRaw` property but that fires as the user is still typing and is too early to trigger a reset in.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to force the update of the component if the state isn't changed and, if the state change, the view will be rendered again anyway.
Forcing updates like that will result in no changes in render.
Usually when formatting dates with moment I check first that raw data is 
suitable to be converted in a date, then I convert it and I've never needed to check it again.

Comment: You can, you can use the `forceUpdate` lifecycle method. Admittedly the React docs advises not to use it but it's available.

Comment: `forceUpdate` is not the problem here, please see the comments above. The issue is that the element refuses to update the input field after blur event (it can be Date.now() or anything else), this answer doesn't help solve that problem.

Comment: Ok I've understood. Try to put the forceUpdate method on the setState callback. IE:  this.setState({date: date.valueOf(),   this.forceUpdate }); Because date is an object the reconciliation may not work as expected.

Comment: Putting forceUpdate in callback worked, I guess date being a complex object was the issue. If you want to update the answer with that, I can accept it.